# Writing comment block for function where parameters change

Tags: php, comments

How best to write the comments for this function where based on the `$data` parameter type behaviours slightly differently.

```
/**
 * Appends data
 *
 * @param mixed - data array
 * @param value
 * @return self
 */
public function addData($data, $value = '')
{
    if(is_array($data)){
        $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $data);
    } else {
        if($value != ''){
            $this->data[$data] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->data[] = $data;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Example:

```
$this->addData($my_array);
$this->addData('my_var', $my_var);
$this->addData($my_var);
```

Update:

```
/**
 * Appends data
 *
 * @param array|string - This can be either an array to be merged
 *                       OR a value to be added to than array
 *                       OR a key if the $value param is set.
 * @param string - If set the first $data parma will be used as the key.
 * @return object
 */
```

Comment: Sorry if there is a better place I should be asking this

Comment: Here are some examples http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.sample.php

Comment: Not an answer, but: To me this seems a *terrible* function. Having the same parameter mean different things is a bad idea, and very confusing. The fact that it's so hard to document is just a symptom of this. If you want to do two different things (merge data into the array, or set a single value), why don't you just provide two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After @param, it should be the type of the variables you pass, if there are several possible types, you can separate them with a |, like this :

```
 /**
 * Appends data
 *
 * @param array|string
 * @param string
 * @return object
 */
```

Are more detailed example, with the type, variable name and description :

```
 /**
 * Appends data
 *
 * @param array|string $parameterOne This is used for...
 * @param string $parameterTwo Optional because...
 * @return object
 */
```

This is the syntax from the PHPDoc website (http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html) :

```
@param datatype1|datatype2 $paramname description
```

Comment: Thanks, although it was a description part that I was finding most difficult. I have updated the question after your suggestions, can you suggest any improvements to this.

Comment: Your description is fine. You forgot to add the $paramname though, it might be a good idea to add it.